# How To Use A War Archive To Run A Java File

Tags: java, html, tcp, war, java-server

I am having a war archive in that i have got five java class files. What i should do to run a java file from that archive . As far as i understood we cant simply call the java file from the html page. 
The file i am supposed to call is a java socket program which is a tcp server. This should be in running state all the time. so that when ever a client tries to connect the server should be available. 
Any possible help is appreciated. if the question is not clear then please be patient enough to ask. I am in a big trouble and need some help

i need to  implement this in a web server too. How can i do the same in a web server

Comment: why do you require a war? Do you only need a standalone commandline tcp server?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Extract war to your server's webapp folder.

Find the .class file in that extracted folder and run it through command line like this : `java className` ...and You're done.

Comment: will doing that help us to run that file continually for 24x7 ?

Comment: That depends on your java class.

Comment: the java class file is a tcp server program that will listen to a client and based on the message received will call up on the other class files to perform the operations

Comment: sorry if i am asking blunder do i have a command line the server ?

Comment: Means you need to start server when the war deploy?

Comment: One solution is that from your welcome page, call the async function of java file which start your server and make it ready to listen.